# Generate files defined by RDL during Visual Studio build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, build, ssrs-2012, rdl

While developing SSRS reports in Visual Studio, we are able to view the reports and then export them into Excel.

As part of our build process, I would like to automate the generation of Excel files during the Visual Studio build. [Then, I will compare the file to an approved version to ensure no regression errors have occurred.]

I would prefer not to use RS.exe, as all report developers would not have SSRS  installed. I am looking for a local option, so that we don't have to deploy to an SSRS server and render from there.

How can I generate exports from the RDL files during the local build process?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own build tool, like a console application that has references to the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms. In order to get the correct assemblies, install the Microsoft Report Viewer Controls (Redistributable Package) from:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723(v=vs.120).aspx

This tool could spin up an instance of a report viewer control, process the report in local processing mode, and return the excel byte stream that can be saved as a file output.